# Webview video Full Screen

Tags: java, android, webview

I have a video player on my website, which was added via Webview, I can see my video, but at the moment of selecting the full-screen button, it does not

This is my class java, all is good, but when I try to push the button of full screen, don't do the function, in my version of mobile and website I can do without problems

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    private AdView mAdView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myWebView);

        myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        myWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        myWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        myWebView.loadUrl("https://spanish.netfoxplus.com");
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    }

    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("spanish.netfoxplus.com")) {
                return false;
            }
            else{
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // Check if the key event was the Back button and if there's history
        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && myWebView.canGoBack()) {
            myWebView.goBack();
            return true;
        }
    // If it wasn't the Back key or there's no web page history, bubble up to the default
    // system behavior (probably exit the activity)
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you have this in you androidManifest.xml `android:screenOrientation="portrait">` ?

Comment: yes, But don't do nothing

Comment: If have that you won't be able to play a video in full-screen because you locked your screen to portrait

Comment: what can to do? what change?

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your webview!

```
webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)");
```

Work perfectly in android 7.0